How to understand likelihood function bayesian
$\mathcal{N}(W^T \cdot X, \beta^{-1})$
This is the likelihood distribution for Bayesian linear regression, right? So, the thing is, if I'm doing batch mode Bayesian regression, then:
Weights (W): Size: (M, 1) or (M,), where M is the number of model parameters.
Input (X): Size: (N, D), where N is the number of data points (training data) and D is the nuumber of basis functions or something like that.
The question is how can we multiply these two vectors and matrix when they aren't even in the same dimension.
I feel like this would have made more sense:
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_{1} & x_{2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
1 & x_{1n} & x_{2n}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
w_{0} \\
w_{1} \\
w_{2}
\end{bmatrix}$
